# Should my unfinished siding be left uncovered when it rains?

Tags: waterproofing, construction, siding

My contractors are re doing my sidings now. The house is left bare as you can see in the pictures is it okay that it's left this way when it's raining or do they have to cover it with tarp or something.[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think you're asking about sheathing, not siding. What we see above the brick are oriented strand board (OSB) sheathing panels. They should not be left exposed to the weather for more than a few weeks (or a few rain events, whichever comes first).

Ideally, housewrap and other components of the drain plane are installed immediately to protect the sheathing and other weather-sensitive parts of your home.

Comment: To add - leaving it exposed for a little rain over a few days isn't going to hurt it, as long as it's allowed to dry properly and the moisture isn't sealed in with home wrap while it's wet.

Comment: Housewrap doesn't seal in moisture. It allows vapor to pass. You're right that it would slow drying, though. Better to not wrap when it's sopping.

Comment: Thanks for all your help I'll make sure to tell them before they add the siding